# How can I display as many Unicode blocks as possible in Android?

Tags: 4.4-kitkat, stock-android, firefox-for-android, fonts

I study linguistics and ancient scripts, and this requires glyphs on high Unicode blocks which most fonts do not support. Unfortunately it seems like most apps in Android will only render the glyphs of whatever primary font is substituted for Roboto-Regular. This is very unsatisfactory because there are no font solutions which even come close to supporting all of Unicode. A mix of several fonts is necessary.

Luckily I do have a godsend in the form of Firefox. I'm not sure if it's due to the fact that they switched rendering engines recently, or if it has always done this, but Firefox will render characters using any font in the system font folder. Meaning even if your primary font doesn't have the glyph, it will still display so long as you have a compatible font somewhere in /system/fonts.

It would be fantastic if the Android system as a whole would do this, but sadly Firefox is the only app I know of that does. None of the other Web browsers work this way including Chrome. If anybody has any suggestions on how to increase font support in other apps like Wikipedia I would appreciate it.